# Unable to get first occurrence elements of //account[1] from xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML with  element on different parents, I am trying to get the first occurrence child elements of  using //account[1] in xslt,

But I still get all the available values from //account. Basically //account & //account[1] are giving same results.

input XMl1

```
<line>
 <accountings>
  <accounting>
    <account>
      <seg1>value1</seg2>
    </account>
  </accounting>
  <accounting>
    <account>
      <seg1>value2</seg2>
    </account>
  </accounting>
 </accountings>
</line>
```

Input xml2

```
<line>
 <account>
  <seg1>value1</seg1>
 </account>
</line>
```

Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="string"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="hello" select="//*:account[1]/>
 <xsl:element name="hello">
   <xsl:value-of select="$hello/*:seg1"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input xml can any of above xmls, that is why i can only use //account, instead of full xpath.

expected output:
     value1

actual output i am getting
    value1 value2

Comment: Your input #1 is not well-formed: `</seg2>` does not close `<seg1>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **Xpath 2.0** [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#abbrev):

> The path expression `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the path expression `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their respective parents.

Comment: That is right, I do want the descendents of first para, let me edit question to make it clear.

Comment: In case my answer wasn't clear: use the `descendant::` axis, not the `//` abbreviation.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually worked /descendant::account[1]

Answer (score 1):

One still can use the `//` abbreviation, but explicitly change the priority of the `[]` predicate by using parenthesis:

**Use**:

```
(//account)[1]
```

**This means**:

1. Select the sequence `//account`
2. From that sequence select the first item

This expression is shorter than `/descendant::account` and probably more readable.

**In contrast, `//account` means**: select all descendant `account` elements that are the first `account` children of their parents.

Because, as defined in the **[W3C XPath 1.0 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev)**:

```
// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/
```